# Why doesn't this code function?

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
local data={}


eventNewPlayer=function(n)
    data[n]={tab="none"}
end

function eventChatCommand(n,c)
    if c == "foo" then

        data[n].tab = c

        if data[n].tab == c then

            ui.removeTextArea(90,n)
        else

            ui.addTextArea(90,"f"..string.rep("o",35),n,400,200,nil,nil)
        end
    end
end

table.foreach(tfm.get.room.playerList,eventNewPlayer)
```

It's a logical error the textarea does not appear whatsoever and I don't really see any error in the code mentioned above

Comment: `data[n].tab = c` `if data[n].tab == c then` `ui.removeTextArea(90,n)` <--- Will always take that path, will never do `ui.addTextArea(...)`

Comment: oh, what can the solution be?

Comment: Try fixing it yourself. I pointed out why `ui.addTextArea` is never called, the rest should be fairly simple.

Comment: if its fairly simple why do you mind telling me the solution

Comment: You learn by exercising your mind, not by being told what to do by others.

Comment: yes but if i could have found the solution i wouldnt be asking here, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `data[n].tab = c` is executed, you are assigning the value of `c` to `data[n].tab`.  This will happen every time that `c == "foo"`.

Therefore, when you execute this:

```
    if data[n].tab == c then

        ui.removeTextArea(90,n)
    else

        ui.addTextArea(90,"f"..string.rep("o",35),n,400,200,nil,nil)
    end
```

It will *always* execute the first part, and not the second part.